# $K[X]_X$ is not integral over $K[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization, integral-extensions

The localization $K[X]_{X}$ is a ring extension of $K[X].$ I want to show that $K[X]_X$ is not integral over $K[X]$ using lying above.

I tried to find a maximal ideal in $K[X]_X$ whose contraction in $K[X]$ is not maximal ideal, or maybe we can produce two prime ideals above one containing another whose contraction is the same prime ideal. I need some help to construct such prime ideals. Thanks.

Comment: Rings of fractions are almost never integral over the original ring.

Comment: Do you mean if $S$ contains a non unit then $S^{-1}A$ is not integral over $A$

Comment: When $A$ is an integral domain, yes.

Comment: See my answer for details on the fundamental property mentioned by @user26857

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second approach cannot work because this does not imply that the lying over property fails. For example, the extension $\Bbb{Z}\subset\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is integral and hence has the lying over property. But the two prime ideals $(2+i),(2-i)\subset\Bbb{Z}[i]$ satisfy
$$(2+i)\cap\Bbb{Z}=(2-i)\cap\Bbb{Z}=5\Bbb{Z},$$
so their contraction is the same prime ideal.

Instead, consider the prime ideal $(X)\subset K[X]$. If there is a prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}\subset K[X]_X$ such that $\mathfrak{q}\cap K[X]=(X)$ then in particular $X\in\mathfrak{q}$. But $X$ is a unit in $K[X]_X$ and so $\mathfrak{q}=K[X]_X$, a contradiction. So there is no prime ideal lying over $(X)$.

For some more perspective; in general when localizing a (commutative unital) ring $R$ with respect to a multiplicative subset $S$, the set of prime ideals of $R_S$ corresponds bijectively to the set of prime ideals of $R$ that are disjoint from $S$. The bijection is given by taking contractions/extensions w.r.t. the localization map $R\ \longrightarrow\ R_S$.

In this particular case, the set of prime ideals of $K[X]_X$ corresponds bijectively to the set of prime ideals of $K[X]$ that do not contain any power of $X$. These are *all* prime ideals except $(X)$, and every prime ideal of $K[X]$ except $(X)$ is the contraction of a prime ideal of $K[X]_X$.

---

[Original answer, where I mistook $K[X]_X$ for $K[X]_{(X)}$.]

As you say, the ring $K[X]_X$ is local, so there is only one maximal ideal, which is the ideal generated by $X$. Its contraction in $K[X]$ is the ideal generated by $X$ there, which is also maximal, so this approach won't work.

The only other prime ideal of $K[X]_X$ is the zero ideal, which contracts to the zero ideal in $K[X]$, which is also prime. So this approach won't work either.

However, this *does* show that the extension does not have the lying over property; the ring $K[X]_X$ has only two prime ideals whereas $K[X]$ has infinitely many. So there must be some prime ideal of $K[X]$ that is not the contraction of a prime ideal of $K[X]_X$.

Comment: $K[X]_X$ is localization wrt the multiplicative closed set $\{1,X,X^2,\ldots\}$

Comment: Ah, I read it as the localization w.r.t. to (the complement of) the prime ideal $(X)$. See my new answer.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't seen a proof like this yet so let me write down:

Suppose otherwise $K[x]_x$ is integral over $K[x]$. Since $1/x\in K[x]_x$, it is the solution of a monic polynomial over $K[x]$, that is:
$$\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^n+f_{n-1} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{n-1}+\cdots+f_0\equiv 0$$
where $f_i\in K[x], i=0, \cdots, n-1$ are the coefficients. Clearing denominators (multiplying both sides with $x^n$) to obtain a polynomial relation in $K[x]$:
$$1+f_{n-1} x+\cdots+f_0 x^n\equiv 0.$$
However this is impossible since the left side has a non-zero constant term: letting $x=0$ gets an equation $1=0$.

Comment: This is just a rearrangement of the proof in my answer ($2$ years prior). I scale by $\,x^{n-1}\,$ to get $\,x^{-1}=g(x)\in K[x]\,$ vs. you scale by $\,x^n\,$ to get $\,1 = xg(x),\,$ i.e. your proof is mine scaled by $\,x.\,$ Both show $x$ is a unit in $K[x]$. I did it that way  because it  clarifies the generalizations I mention.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a *conceptual* view:  a *crucial* ($\rm\color{#c00}{characteristic})$ property of *integral* ring extensions is that they don't alter *unit* properties in the base ring, i.e. a nonunit $\,r\in R\,$ remains a nonunit in any integral extension ring $S.\,$ [For example, this may allow us to deduce that Diophantine equations in $\Bbb Z$ are unsolvable by deducing a parity contradiction $\,2\,|\,1\,$ in any [number ring with parity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26843/242), or [a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/48533/242) that $(9+4\sqrt{5})^n + (9-4\sqrt{5})^n$ is even]. Thus the  [nonunit $X\in R[X]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2523/242) must remain a nonunit in any integral extension (so the OP extension is not integral since it inverts $X$)

A proof is easy: below specialize $\,u \in R\,$ to get $\,\bbox[3px,border:1px solid #c00]{u^{-1}\text{ is integral over }R\! \iff\! u^{-1}\in\ R\,}$

**Lemma** $ $ Suppose  $\,R\subset S\,$ is an integral extensions of commutative rings and $\,u\,$ is a unit in $S$. Then $u^{-1}$ is integral over $R\iff u^{-1}\in R[u]$

$\begin{align}{\bf Proof}\ \ \ u^{-1}\ \text{is integral over } R&\iff u^{-n} =  r_{1} u^{-(n-1)}+\cdots +\, r_n,\:\! \ \ \ \ {\rm for\ some}\ \ r_i\in R\\
 &\!\!\overset{\times\ u^{\large n-1}\!\!}\iff u^{-1} =\,  r_{1}\ +\ \cdots\,\ +\,\ r_n\, u^{n-1},\ \ {\rm for\ some}\ \ r_i\in R \end{align}$

**Generalization** $ $ More generally it is [easy to prove](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3129524/242) that $R[u]\cap R[u^{-1}]\,$ is integral over $R$.

Viewed in terms of ideals the key property is: $ $ principal ideals $\:\!(r)\:\!$ *survive* in integral extensions, i.e. $\, rR\neq 1\,\Rightarrow\, rS\neq 1.\,$ Integral extensions can be nicely $\rm\color{#c00}{characterized}$ by various *universal* forms of such ideal survivability, e.g. see the paper of Coykendall and Dobbs [cited here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/57702/242)