# The notion of "units" is independent of the base algebraic integer ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, integral-extensions, algebraic-integers

Consider the ring $\mathcal O$ of all algebraic integers and a subring $\mathcal A\subset \mathcal O$. If $u\in\mathcal A$ is invertible in $\mathcal O$, then is the inverse of $u$ necessarily in $\mathcal A$?

In other words, if $u\in\mathcal A$ is invertible in $\mathcal O$, then is $u$ invertible in $\mathcal A$?

This seems like a very fundamental question. Are there any contexts I could refer to so I could better understand the related topics?

Comment: One approach: if $u$ is in $\mathcal{A}$, then $u$ is in some number field $K/\mathbb{Q}$. Consider the Galois closure $\overline{K}$ with Galois group $G$. In $\overline{K}$, we can write $u^{-1} = \pm \prod_{\sigma \neq 1} (\sigma u)$, where $\sigma$ ranges over $G$. Each $\sigma u$ is also an algebraic integer, as the Galois action preserves the algebraic polynomial. There's probably a simpler way, but this jumped out at me.

Comment: @davidlowryduda I don't quite follow your argument. Certainly, the Galois conjugates of $u$ belong to $\mathcal{O}$, but why should they belong to $\mathcal{A}$? And if they don't, why does their product?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3137826/242) in the dupe for this and generalizations (including how to *characterize* integral extensions by a closely related "survival" property).

Comment: I strongly vote for removing the [duplicate] tag. First thing is that OP may have never heard about localizations and may therefore not be able to follow the comments and answers in the linked post (which is not a fault on the OP's side). Second, if a different question may have answers containing some ideas which are useful for OP's question doesn't make it "duplicate". @BillDubuque, that's not a criticism of your comment. Just mentioning in the comments (or even in an answer) that there is another post with useful ideas is totally fine of course.

Comment: ... and forgot the third point: the questions are simply not the same.

Comment: @russo The OP does not need to know anything about localizations to understand [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3137826/242) in the dupe (the answer they accepted below is essentially the same).   Duplicate closure doesn't require that the *questions* are the same (cf. the SE banner: "this question already has answers here"). See also [abstract duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1756/242).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes.  The reason is that $u\in\mathcal{O}$ is a root of its minimal polynomial
$$
X^n+a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\dots+a_0\in\mathbb{Z}[X].
$$
where $n=[\mathbb{Q}(u):\mathbb{Q}]$.  Now for $u\in\mathcal{A}$ invertible in $\mathcal{O}$, we get
$$
a_0(u^{-1})^n+a_1(u^{-1})^{n-1}+\dots + a_{n-1}u^{-1}+1=0
$$
and so $a_0X^n+a_1X^{n-1}+\dots+a_{n-1}+1$ is up to constant multiple the minimal (monic integer-coefficient) polynomial of $u^{-1}\in\mathcal{O}$ (since $\mathbb{Q}(u^{-1})=\mathbb{Q}(u)$).  So we have $a_0=\pm 1$ and $u^{-1}=\pm (u^{n-1}+a_{n-1}u^{n-2}+\dots + a_1)\in\mathbb{Z}[u]\subseteq\mathcal{A}$.